# Devenv deployment parameters

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, report

I have a report project that I want to script deploying to a development server.  I need to just change the TargetServerUrl in the project properties.  Is there a way to do this?

i.e.

&devenv.exe RSReports.sln /project Reports\Reports.rptproj /deploy

maybe => properties:TargetServerUrl=http://myserver/ReportServer

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about report projects but in almost every VS project you can define multiple "Configuration"s (the defaults are *Debug* and *Release*). So you can have one target in debug and another in Release mode, and use the command line

```
devenv /deploy Release RSReports.sln
```

Another option is to use the [msbuild.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) utility to build your project (instead of devenv), and use it's proprerty replacemnet parameter

```
"c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" "Full path to soulution" /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:TargetServerUrl=http://myserver/ReportServer
```